# Edit and reload MVC 4 model with jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am wondering if there is a way to edit a MVC 4 model then reload the view with the new model from jQuery. The basics of what I am trying to do is I have a page that has weeks of dates and text boxes after each date. This page is for a time card site. The model contains the days of the week and the name of the days for that date. What I am want to modify is the dates in the model so if a user is on this week and realizes they forgot to enter there time for last week they can click a button that takes the to enter time for the last week. I have function to get the dates and the days of the week just not sure how to edit the model and reload it.

The site controllers in C# code samples or any idea would be helpful.

Comment: Can you show the code you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into communicating with your server using [jQuery/AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Serialize you model into `JSON`, modify it in your controller and send it back. You can then update your view with the new data.

Comment: sweet I will look into that i really did not have any code yet it was more of a where to start and what are the steps to do this which you answered.

Comment: done. This is not the exact way i did it but this would have worked too. I just ended up using jquery to call the function in the controller then return the view with the updated controller.